# Error while running Java app

Tags: intellij-idea

The log shows this

```
"error=2, No such file or directory"

"Cannot run program /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/.. " and a path to a directory that exists.
```

I could replicate the error running a "hello world" app without any type of dependencies and configs (no maven, no spring).

I'm using Intellij 2016, and OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 31):

The problem was with the SDK that was referencing the one that is bundled inside Intellij.

I could solve it by changing the sdk and referencing the one outside Intellij.
This can be done going to **File > Project Structure > SDKs** and in "JDK Home Path" put the path to the SDK (in my case `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home`).

Comment: Ok, for some reason XX in "jdk1.8.0_XX" got screwed and that folder never existed, i had to reassign it

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov : thanks, that was what happened. Your comment helped.